# Read Only File System view files within .zip

Tags: linux, zip, readonly

I am working with a read only file system through Putty SSH. I have lots of zip files which contain multiple directories. I want to read a .kml file stored within one of these sub-directories. Is there a way to do this?

I have accessed the list of files with `unzip -l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unzip -p archive.zip the-file-name-here
```

From the [unzip man page](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/unzip.html):

> -p
>
> extract files to pipe (stdout). Nothing but the file data is sent to stdout, and the files are always extracted in binary format, just as they are stored (no conversions).